# C# How to build list of objects and change their properties

Tags: c#, list, object

I just scrapped the entire previous question for a more basic situation:
I want to make a simple load + display program such as when I load a text file, the file name, the file path and the contents are displayed in 3 different textboxes.

Here is the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListBuilderTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class TextFile
        {
            public string TextFilePath {get;set;}
            public string TextFileTitle {get;set;}
            public string TextFileString {get;set;}
        }
        List<TextFile> TextFileList = new List<TextFile>();


        string pathToFile = "";
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text files|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    foreach (String file in ofd.FileNames)
                    {
                        TextFile CurrentFile = new TextFile();
                        CurrentFile.TextFilePath = ofd.SafeFileName;
                        CurrentFile.TextFileTitle = ofd.FileName;
                        if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) {

                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
                            {
                                CurrentFile.TextFileString = sr.ReadLine();
                            }
                        }
                        TextFileList.Add(CurrentFile);

                        /*
                        textBox.Text = CurrentFile.TextFileTitle+"\r\n";
                        textBox_Copy.Text = CurrentFile.TextFilePath+"\r\n";
                        textBox_Copy1.Text = CurrentFile.TextFileString+"\r\n";*/
/* I would like to simplify this preceeding code into displaying it as a reference to the list rather than the current object.*/
                     }
                }
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

The OFD works and I can select multiple files however, it will only obtain the properties of the first file.

My files are Apple.txt, Banana.txt and Cherry.txt and they each respectively contain "Red", "Yellow" and "Black".

Comment: if you debug it you will see its obtaining all of them, but your textboxes are overwritten each time ... so you see values of last one

try:
textBox.Text += CurrentFile.TextFileTitle+"\r\n";
textBox_Copy.Text += CurrentFile.TextFilePath+"\r\n";
textBox_Copy1.Text += CurrentFile.TextFileString+"\r\n";

Comment: Good catch! However, it always reads the last file (everything is Apple.txt). At least it's getting me further than before. Thanks! Working on it!

Answer (score 0):

you will add something to list like this:

```
PDFList.Add(new PDFfile { PDFFileName = "name", PDFText = "text" });
```

your foreach cycle should be like this:

```
foreach (PDFfile file in PDFList){
    if(Regex.IsMatch(file.PDFText, "statement") == true)
    {
       file.PDFresult1 = "true";
    } 
    else
    {
       file.PDFresult1 = "false";
    }
}
```

the rest should be fine

Comment: I cannot call PDFList, I am not sure why. I wrote in List<PDFfile> PDFList = new List<PDFfile>(); but if I write PDFList afterwards, it is not recognized.

For the foreach loop you gave, I can sort of see the logic but VS cannot, it cannot convert a string type to a PDFfile type.